# UIActivityindicatorView within label possible?

Tags: iphone

anyone can give the detail how to do it?please see that link?

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?c66c4d2054.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Those activity labels are part of the Three20 iPhone UI library by Joe Hewitt.

http://github.com/joehewitt/three20

Comment: Study the code.  It is easier than us telling you how to do it.